# Automatic SMS notification on iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, sms

I want to notify the user with automatic SMS notification on iOS device. My app is the iOS application. Whenever there is some updated news, I want to notify the user with automatic SMS notification. I found out that I can use Twilio. 
Is there any other way to notify the users with iOS SMS notification system?

Comment: Why do you want to use SMS when you can use a push notification for free?

Comment: Yea, my company will use both, like push notifications to notify the trades and stuffs and SMS notifications to notify the latest news.... @Paulw11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several option available for send SMS to iOS application users.

- [plivo](https://www.plivo.com/sms-api/)
- [nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/)
- [Spring Edge](https://www.springedge.com)
- [sinch](https://www.sinch.com/)
- [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notifications)

You need to consider several things before chose any platform like cost, performance, extensibility, easy to integrate, etc...

you can use below link to compare couple of platform : Blog

http://nextjuggernaut.com/blog/sms-voice-api-twilio-vs-nexmo-plivo-sinch-mobile-app-guide/#!prettyPhoto

Hope this help.

Comment: @Emory anytime :)